# what is the best way to build android app-server system which can play live streaming service?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, streaming

I'm a developer from korea.(sorry about my broken english previously :( )

I will make android app which can play live streaming movie(1min, 6~7Mb) with web-server.
(At least 20000~30000 users may connect to this at the same time)
I don't want to waste my time to set up some server, DB..etc so i decided to use google app engine to do easily.

However, one of my peer said to me that google app engine doesn't suit live-streaming service and he recommanded using google app engine service with google cloud storage.

My first question is,
is that good using google app engine service with google cloud storage for this now?
If so, it assures good-streaming quality?(even korea, not USA. i mean in terms of the location of IDC)

second question is,
If not, how about using Google app engine with the mobile streaming hosting service in korea? is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appengine is not for streaming. google storage is in beta and you don't want to build your product using beta product. google storage serve static file, you want "live". so even if google storage is out of beta, I don't think it will meet your need. if you have a separate CDN for streaming, you can use appengine. you can look at my proof of concept here appengine+android streaming radio station
http://poc-radio.aunndroid.com